# Theory of convergent series in topological groups?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, topological-groups

In the real numbers, under the standard topology, there exist sequences $ \{x_n\} $, with $x_n \neq 0 $ such that the infinite sum

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x_n
$$

converges.

However, in the integers, under addition, no such series exists. Perhaps the series $x_{2n} = 1$, $x_{2n + 1} = -1$, could be considered convergent, but this feels like it depends a lot on the topology, and I feel like there should be some natural sense in which it is not considered convergent (I guess when viewed as a subspace/group of the real numbers).

Is there a theory which answers the question: Which groups have non-trivial convergent series? Is this even an interesting/well formed question?

Comment: Not sure why you don't look at sequences instead of series, this way no need to assume an "addition". For your question, any group not having the discrete topology. You can embed $\Bbb{Z}$ into $\Bbb{Q}_p$ to get $\lim_{n\to \infty} p^n=0$.

Comment: Such groups are topological groups having a countable base for the family of open neighbourhoods of the identity element.

Comment: The concept of convergence is defined in terms of the topology. So your second paragraph doesn't make sense. If we equip the reals with the discrete topology, then we get a topological group in which the only convergent sequences are the ones that are eventually constant.